# What does "Injection" means in Constructor Injection and Dependency Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, terminology, constructor-injection

I have read about dependency injection. Then there comes

- Constructor Injection,
- Getter Injection
- Setter Injection
- Interface Injection

How do they differ from Dependency Injection or all of them are same?  What do **Injection** Means here? Just giving the required Object/Parameter to the class? Like Construction injection means passing the required parameter as the constructor parameter? or am i missing something?

Comment: Do you understand the word "inject"?

Comment: something from outside is inject into the inside of an object. solution for loose coupling and to make wirering of bean dependencys manageable by a framework. so in general your suggestions are correct.

Answer (score 8):

- **Dependency Injection** is the act of supplying a class with its dependencies by supplying them by a third-party. The 'injection' of 'Dependency Injection' simply means 'supplying/providing/passing a dependency to a class from the outside/third-party'. The history around the origin of the term is a bit muddy, but I believe 'injection' was chosen as a term to contrast opposing patterns where the consumer would 'request' or 'pull' its dependency in from some sort of central repository or locator.
- [Constructor Injection](https://freecontent.manning.com/understanding-constructor-injection/) is the most common form of **Dependency Injection**. **Constructor Injection** is the act of statically defining the list of required dependencies by specifying them as parameters to the class's constructor.
- **Setter Injection** (a.k.a. [Property Injection](https://freecontent.manning.com/understanding-property-injection/)) and [Method Injection](https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns) (with **Interface Injection** being a specialization of **Method Injection**) are alternative forms of supplying (or 'injecting') the dependency into the consuming class.
- *Getter Injection*, to my knowledge, doesn't exist. A Getter is only able to *retrieve* values, not *setting* them, which is a requirement for Dependency *Injection*.

So **Constructor Injection**, **Setter Injection** and **Interface Injection** are all *forms* of **Dependency Injection**. **Constructor Injection** is the most common form of DI and it forces a class to be created with *all* its required dependencies. **Constructor Injection** should therefore be your preferred form of DI. There are cases however where **Method Injection** or **Property Injection** make sense as well. The book [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://mng.bz/BYNl) (by Mark Seemann and I) goes into a lot of detail about these forms of DI (especially [chapter 4](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-4)).

Comment: Very Nice Answer

Answer (score 3):

Then there is `@Inject` constructor in Dagger 2 and that is something different and might be mistaken for this by junior developers. It looks like this:

```
ListAdapter @Inject constructor() : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListViewHolder>() {
//code
}
```

The above is Kotlin, in Java it looks like this:

```
class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListViewHolder>() {

@Inject
public ListAdapter(Context context) {

}

}
```

It is feature of Dagger 2 that allows you to generate `@Provides` without actually writing `@Provides` functions / voids in modules.

By annotating the constructor with inject you also told dagger that there is a class called X and you need a context for it to be instantiated. It is basically the same as adding it to your module.

Answer (score 0):

The three forms of dependency injection are constructor, setter, interface [and a 4th, contextual]. I've never heard of Getter Injection so I won't refer to it. Injection is simply *how* an object or component is related to another object or component, usually a class. Without dependency injection, components are considered to be 'tightly coupled' if they have any form of association. For example, consider this class (written in Java) that does not utilize dependency injection:

```
public class Salesman implements Worker {
     private Car itemForSale;
     public Salesman() {
          itemForSale = new Car("BMW");
     }
     public void printItemSold() {
          System.out.println("The salesman sold a " + itemForSale.name() 
          + " at price $"+itemForSale.price());
     }
}
```

Here, the Salesman class is tightly coupled to the Car class. Consider that the saleman may *actually* sell parts, tools, and services as well. However, the itemForSale field is a Car object, and the default constructor here is setting the itemForSale to a Car object. We would have slightly looser coupling if we changed the constructor to `public Salesman(String carName, double carPrice)`, but still, that would not decouple Salesman and Cars - a Saleman object still 'depends on' a Car object for its functionality.

Now, here is an example of constructor dependency injection:

```
public class Salesman implements Worker {
     private Item itemForSale;
     public Salesman(Item item){
          itemForSale = item;
     }
     public void printItemSold(){
          System.out.println("salesman sold a " + itemForSale");
     }
}
```

Now we can write in another class:

```
Item car = new Car("Jeep", 8900); // the Car class implements the Item item class/interface
Salesman salesman = new Salesman(car);
salesman.printItemSold();

Item part = new Part("tires", 67.99); // the Part class also implements the Item class/interface
Salesman salesman = new Salesman(part);
salesman.printItemSold();

... and so on.
```

The key benefit here, which may be difficult to see in such a simple case, is that the Salesman object is not dependent whatsoever on the Car class. In order to encompass all of the different types of objects to be sold, we do not need a Car field, a Part field, a Service field, etc. nor do we need to implement logic such as

```
if (car != null) 
     printItemSold(car) 
else if (part != null)
     printItemSold(part)
...
```

Rather, all we need to do is simply provide (or inject) the Item that salesman sold to the Salesman object.

Setter injection works in roughly the same way except it uses a setter instead of a constructor. This can be beneficial if we want to change the object sold without having to make a new object each time.

```
public class Salesman implements Worker {
     private Item itemForSale;
     public Salesman() { }
     public void setItem(Item item){
          this.itemForSale = item;
     }
     ...
}
```

Now we can do:

```
Salesman salesman = new Salesman();
salesman.setItem(new Car("Toyota", 23938.23);
salesman.print();
salesman.setItem(new Service("oil change", 17.78);
salesman.print();
```

I think it's safe to say that constructor injection is usually implemented along with setter injection, since once you implement the former form, it is very easy to implement the latter.

I'm won't going to go into interface injection since I have not used it before and may give you the wrong info. In case you happen to be using Java Spring, know that Spring only utilizes constructor and setter injection - not interface.

Lastly, contextual dependency injection is not exactly what most people have in mind when they use the term dependency injection. But for me, it is what I cared about most when trying to learn what dependency injection is (Sorry if the following explanation is not as helpful - it's hard for me to give an explanation in any other terms than Java Spring). Say you have an complex object like a database connection that has numerous fields and a lifecycle that should be carefully managed.

You *could* set this as a field in your class, configure it, establish or open it, begin and end transactions, and ensure that it is closed by the time your program has terminated, all on your own. However, it would be nice if all you had to do was simply declare that you want a connection object, and then have that connection managed for you. The connection opens only when it is needed, when you call `connection.save(data)`, a transaction automatically begins and commits, and when you terminate your program, and the connection is automatically closes no matter what, even if you have an exception or an error. In Java Spring for example, this would simply involve an `@Component` or `@Bean` annotation in your Connection class, and then declare `@Autowired Connection connection // the Connection will even be constructed for you` in any class that is utilizing the connection.

This has become a big deal in the programming world. To see why, say you have a connection that takes in a Driver object like a MySQLDriver, MSSQLDriver, or PostgresDriver. Of course, each one of those drivers is implemented differently, and requires a unique set of configurations. But with the managed connection object you are asking for in the declaring class, all you need to do when changing from one database to the next is utilize a form of constructor or setter injection:  `Connection conn = new Connection(MSSQLDriver);` or `@Autowired Connection conn; conn.setDriver(PostgresDriver);` This can save hours of time and eliminate the need to learn complex 'boilerplate' code, since all you have to do is make a single change to our field, and your object will be managed accordingly.

And FYI, this is a 'you don't know it unless you explain it' post, so feel free to correct me if I made a mistake.